# Why is this code generating segmentation fault?

Tags: c, linked-list

I was trying to implement the insertion of nodes to a singly linked list.The compiler produced segmentation error in the traversal part of the code.

```
struct Node *start=NULL;

void traverse() 
{
    struct Node *t;
    t=start;
    if(t==NULL)
    {
        printf("Linked list is empty\n");
        return;
    }
    printf("there are %d elements in linked list",count);

    while (t != NULL) 
    { 
        printf(" %d ",t->data); 
        t=t->next; 
    } 
    printf(" %d ",t->data);
}
```

After running the code:

```
Shaons-Air:VSC shaon$ cd "/Users/shaon/Desktop/VSC/" && gcc linkedlist.c -o linkedlist && "/Users/shaon/Desktop/VSC/"linkedlist
1.insert at the beginning2.insert at the end3.traverse
1
enter element
2
1.insert at the beginning2.insert at the end3.traverse
1
enter element
3
1.insert at the beginning2.insert at the end3.traverse
3
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Comment: What's in `start`?

Comment: Start by running a debug build in an actual debugger, to catch the crash as and when it happens. That will allow you to locate where in your code it happens, and also to examine values of variables to see if their values look okay and valid. If you want more help from us you have to provide a [mcve] that replicates the crash. Also refresh [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Please put the complete code.

Comment: And some nitpicking, it isn't the compiler that produced the crash, it's a bug in your code that caused it.

Comment: @VivekGaur It will become clumsy if I put up the whole code.Btw it's not necessary to look into the whole code

Comment: Show us the "remaining part" ? How can we be sure that `start` updated correctly ? or you are doing `NULL->`

Comment: The code you posted does not cause a seg fault.

Comment: The whole code is not required, but a [mcve] is required.

Comment: *it's not necessary to look into the whole code* - yes it is. A bug in one place in the code can cause a problem in an unrelated part of the code. So if you trim the code down to a minimal example, and the problem goes away, then the bug was in the part you removed.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this code:

```
while (t != NULL)   // Keep repeating until t is NULL
{ 
    printf(" %d ", t->data); 
    t=t->next; 
} 
printf(" %d ",t->data);  // Now t is NULL but still you dereference it ...
              ^^^
              dereference a NULL
```

So you go on until `t` is `NULL` and then you do `t->data` !! That's a crash.

Simply delete the last `printf` as you have already printed all elements.

Comment: Lol - don't ever say that.  Your computer will now spontaneously explode.

Answer (score 1):

So when t is pointing to the last node

t->next = null
and you do

```
t = t->next;
```

> // so t = null

so then when you do

> printf("%d", t->data);

it creates seg fault as t is null and doesn't have any data part